# read file txt by column in C++

Tags: c++, file, line

I have file.txt with this structure (in picture):[image]

and I want to read this file and i'dont know if there is a methode to read file by column because when i get for exemple 25 from my file i need to know that it is the VEHICLE NUMBER.

I think use to lines to do this!! any idea please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no function in C++ to read a file by column. You have to write your own function to do that.

A text file is stored on disk line-by-line, so you have to read the whole file line-by-line and on each line parse out the column data you are interested in.